# My Tic-tac-toe game will only print a win statement for X and not O, despite having the same code for each

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

When X wins the game, it successfully prints "X won!" but when Y wins, the message is not printed.

```
def getMove(b):
    draw = False

    while checkwin(b) != True:

        # X moves
        xin = 0
        xin = int(input("X move:\n"))
        if xin > 9 or xin < 1:
            return "Error: Please enter a number 1-9"
        if type(xin) is not int:
            return "Error: Please enter a number 1-9"
        # Replace number with X or Y using delete and insert
        del b[(xin-1)]
        b.insert((xin - 1), "X")

        print("The board is:\n")
        showBoard(b)

        # Check win/draw
        draw = checkdraw(b)
        if checkwin(b) == True:
            xcount = 0
            ycount = 0
            for each in b:
                if each == "X":
                    xcount += 1
                if each == "Y":
                    ycount += 1
            if xcount > ycount:
                print("X won!")
            if ycount > xcount:
                print("Y won!")

        if checkdraw(b) == True and checkwin(b) != True:
            print("Draw!")
            break


        if checkwin(b) != True:

            # Y moves
            yin = 0
            yin = int(input("Y move:\n"))
            if yin > 9 or yin < 1:
                return "Error: Please enter a number 1-9"
            if type(yin) is not int:
                return "Error: Please enter a number 1-9"
            del b[(yin-1)]
            b.insert((yin-1), "Y")

            print("The board is:\n")
            showBoard(b)

            draw = checkdraw(b)

            if checkwin(b) == True:
                xcount = 0
                ycount = 0
                for each in b:
                    if each == "X":
                        xcount += 1
                    if each == "Y":
                        ycount += 1
                if xcount > ycount:
                    print("X won!")
                if ycount > xcount:
                    print("Y won!")
            else:
                getMove(b)


def checkwin(b):
    # X
    if b[0] == "X" and b[3] == "X" and b[6] == "X":
        return True
    if b[0] == "X" and b[4] == "X" and b[8] == "X":
        return True
    if b[0] == "X" and b[1] == "X" and b[2] == "X":
        return True
    if b[1] == "X" and b[4] == "X" and b[7] == "X":
        return True
    if b[2] == "X" and b[4] == "X" and b[6] == "X":
        return True
    if b[2] == "X" and b[5] == "X" and b[8] == "X":
        return True
    if b[3] == "X" and b[4] == "X" and b[5] == "X":
        return True
    if b[6] == "X" and b[7] == "X" and b[8] == "X":
        return True

    #Y
    if b[0] == "Y" and b[3] == "Y" and b[6] == "Y":
        return True
    if b[0] == "Y" and b[4] == "Y" and b[8] == "Y":
        return True
    if b[0] == "Y" and b[1] == "Y" and b[2] == "Y":
        return True
    if b[1] == "Y" and b[4] == "Y" and b[7] == "Y":
        return True
    if b[2] == "Y" and b[4] == "Y" and b[6] == "Y":
        return True
    if b[2] == "Y" and b[5] == "Y" and b[8] == "Y":
        return True
    if b[3] == "Y" and b[4] == "Y" and b[5] == "Y":
        return True
    if b[6] == "Y" and b[7] == "Y" and b[8] == "Y":
        return True
    else:
        return False

def checkdraw(b):
    bsum = 0
    for each in b:
        if type(each) is int:
            bsum += each
    while bsum != 0 and winner == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

There are no errors. It only falls out of the function instead of printing "You win" message for player Y.

Comment: How do i even run this?

Comment: Hi, you still have a lot of work ahead but don't be discouraged by small bugs. Try to use an IDE to debug the code. Start with small fixes, like the extra "else" in checkwin that is incorrect, or removing the while that could potentially end in an infinite loop in your checkdraw function. Just use an if condition. You can also have the same amount of X and Y, but have a winner. Rewrite the algorithm. Maybe rewrite the checkwin function to also receive X or Y character and make it more generic? Good luck! Coding takes time. You just need patience and practice.

Comment: @U9-Forward, apparently getMove(b) is actually the main loop. You call it with an array of length 9. I think the array is supposed to be filled with ones. I'm not sure.